# Most pythonic way to find the maximum elements out of list of np.array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list of `np.array`, `mya = [a0,...,an]` (all of which have the same shape and dtype). Say `ai` has the shape `ai = array[xi0,xi1,..,xim]`. I want to get

```
[max((a[i] for a in mya)) for i in range(m)]
```

. For example, let `x=np.array([3,4,5])`, `y=np.array([2,50,-1])` and `z=np.array([30,0,3])` then for `mya = [x,y,z]`, I want `[30,50,5]` (or `np.array` equivalent).

Giving `m` by `m=len(mya[0])`, my code above does work, but it seems way too tedious. What are the suggested ways to achieve this?

Comment: did you tried `np.amax(...)`?

Comment: @RubenBermudez `np.amax(mya)` gives just `50` for above example but `np.amax(mya,axis=0)` worked like a magic. Thanks

Comment: sorry, I had to leave a moment and forgot to click *post* on my answer explaining the `axis`. I've just posted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In numpy, `numpy.amax(myarray)` give you the maximum of `myarray`. If you look for the maximum of each list/array of first dimmension, you can set also the *axis* you want. In this case, it should be:

```
x=np.array([3,4,5])
y=np.array([2,50,-1])
z=np.array([30,0,3])
mya = [x,y,z] 
maximum = np.amax(mya, axis=0)
# maximum will store a list as [maximumofx, maximumofy, maximumofz] -> [30,50,5]
```

See [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html)

Answer (score 0):

As @Ruben_Bermudez suggested, `np.amax` was just what I was looking for.

`np.amax`, scipy documentation provided [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.amax.html), accepts an array-like data as input and returns "the maximum of an array or maximum along an axis." Among its optional parameters is `axis`, which specifies the axis along which to find maximum.

By default, input is flattened, so

```
np.amax(mya) # => 50
```

Specifying `axis=0`

```
np.amax(mya,axis=0)  # np.array([30,50,5])
```

and this was what I wanted.

Sorry for the mess.

Comment: Expand your answer to show how you did it, then accept your own answer.